# Azure AD B2C need to add a custom page

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am working on an Azure B2C custom policy. I would like to insert a custom consent page when the user signs in asking him for his consent to allow us to access his data etc. within the custom policy XML How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a custom policy, there is a sample here: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/service-consent

Comment: Hello Jas, is there a way we can access the permission scopes and display them, just like we would on a regular Azure AD